# How to use matplotlib to animate bubble plot along with years

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot, matplotlib-animation

The following dataset needs to be animated with years as a bubble plot. With the year, Life Expectancy(X-Axis) and GDP(Y-Axis) need to be changed.

```
df.head()
```

[image]

Following Image for the Year of 1960 :

[image]

Following Image for Year 1961 :

[image]

My requirement is to animate Life-Expectancy vs GDP graph along with years.
But when I tried to animate the graph using the below code, the result is not as expected.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

s = ax.scatter([], [])

def animate_(i):

    # clear the axis each frame
    ax.clear()
    
    # replot things
    s = ax.scatter("LifeExpectency",
                   "GDP_in_log2",
                   alpha=0.5,
                   s='population',
                   c='colorForContinent',
                  data = df)
    return s,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate_, frames = 62 , interval=500, blit=False)

#anim.save('Countries progression.mp4')
```

> Following the image i got. It means all the year output merge one
> another. Any idea how to sort this out.
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tie `i` in `animate_` to the `Year` by filtering `df`

try `df[df['Year'] == some_function(i)]`

where `some_function(i)` maps the frame count to the year selected

Answer (score 1):

Because there are too many data points in the figure. It's not a good idea to show all the country data over all the years.
(1) One year per image, like your first two figures
(2) A few (e.g., 5) countries per image over all the years. The expected result is that data points of the same country will overlap with each other. But different countries may be separate.

In short, you need to find some angle to split the third figure since too many data hurts visualization.